# What is the correct regex for this?

Tags: regex

I have a long txt file like this:

```
notes = "asdfasasfs";
name = "Bob Field";
time = "08:00";
address = "123 Apple Road";
phone = "555-1234";
zip = "33456";
date = "2021-03-29 23:00:00 +0000";
```

This repeats thousands of times for different people.

I want to list just `time` and `zip` and display them side by side like

```
time = "08:00" ... zip = "33456"
time = "10:00" ... zip = "11123"
time = "13:00" ... zip = "43567"
time = "17:00" ... zip = "37754"
```

I have tried this regex

```
.*(time.*\".*\";).*(zip.*\".*\";).*
```

expecting to use it later like

```
$1 ... $2
```

but this is not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: why try some monster regex, why not try a sequence of regexes?

Comment: sorry, my knowledge of regex is very limited.

Comment: Well it's going to remain very limited if you don't break the problem down. You can look into how to delete lines you don't want.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: @Toto - the file contains stuff in English and Portuguese, but basically english, UTf8

Comment: @Toto   If you ask what tool.. then, since he's asking re a regex then you might want to know how much regex support there is, eg if there's PCRE, or if it's perl, support for lookaheads.   / good regex support.   And as for language/tool the only other relevant thing would be if it supports loops.  It's better to inform rather than to hide your thinking.  i.e. better to inform than to hide the thinking behind your question.

Comment: I don't ask spoken language but programming language.

Comment: @Toto Again. every programming language has iteration, if that's what you have in mind. You should state the thinking behind your question, instead of hiding it

Comment: @barlop: I just ask in order to give a correct regex that depends on language.

Comment: Is [that](https://regex101.com/r/duml45/1) what you want?

Comment: @Toto, that's it. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your problem with this regex:

```
[\s\S]+?^(time .+);[\s\S]+?^(zip =.+?);[\s\S]+?$
```

and replace with: `$1 ... $2`

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/duml45/1/)

This is working for many regex flavour.

Comment: The `[\s\S]+` is that because you don't want to say `.+` because if you said `.+` then you'd have to ensure that dot matches new line is checked. So you do `[\s\S]+` to ensure new lines are matched?   Is `dot matches newline` a default in programming languages regex engines?

Comment: @barlop: In most (all ?) regex flavour, `.` doesn't match newline, if you want to activate this behaviour, you have to use the `dot matches newline` flag, that's done with `s` flag or, if the regex engine accept it, the inline flag `(?s)`. So the actual regex becomes `(?s).+?^(time [^\r\n;]+);.+?^(zip =[^\r\n;]+);.+?$`

Answer (score 1):

if every set will have one and exactly one of each of "Time" and "Zip", then this works great:

```
$ egrep '^(time|zip)' < in | paste - - | sed -e 's/;/ .../; s/;//'
time = "08:00" ... zip = "33456"
time = "08:01" ... zip = "33457"
time = "08:02" ... zip = "33458"
time = "08:03" ... zip = "33459"
```

(I simulated such an input by repeating your example 3 more times with different values of time and zip)

Comment: `time` & `zip` have to be separated with `... ` and semicolons have to be removed.

Comment: easy enough; done